# How to iterate through two dimensions list with Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have a variable like that :

```
"files": {
    "results": [
        {
            "files": [
                {
                    "path": "/etc/file1.xml", 
                }, 
                {
                    "path": "/etc/file2.xml", 
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "files": [
                {
                    "path": "/etc/file2.xml", 
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "files": []
        }
    }
}
```

How can iterate through all paths ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate two dimensions to get all paths.
Use [map](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#map) filter to reduce your original list.

To get plain list of paths from your example:

```
- debug: msg="{{ files.results | map(attribute='files') | sum(start=[]) | map(attribute='path') | list }}"
```

Comment: Is there a way to use a smaller line with lookup plugin `flattened` ?

Comment: Failed, I have this error: `template error while templating string: no filter named 'map'`

Comment: `map` is the standard jinja2 filter. There's something with your setup, or very ancient Ansible version.

Comment: I found this issue: https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/issues/447. I seems map was introduced in jinja2 2.7 and I'm using jinja2 2.6.1.